Flutter MacOS Release Build runs on one MacBook, not on another
The application is not running on different macbook
I attempted to build the flutter macos release build on Macbook Pro 2019 using the following command:

flutter build macos --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./debug-info

The release build works perfectly on my MacBook. However, when I tried to run it on other MacBooks with both Intel and Apple Silicon chips, it failed to run. I've attached a screenshot of the issue for reference.


No screenshots seem to be added.

please check its added now

I resolved the issue by converting the .app file to a .dmg extension.
